# Airflow 1.10: Wrong logfile path

Tags: python, airflow

After upgrading to Airflow 1.10 I'm no longer able to read logs through the webserver. However Airflow is correctly producing logs and saving them to disk.

From the task instance details I can see that the listed `log_filepath` is wrong.
According to task instance details the `log_filepath` is this for example: `/home/ubuntu/airflow/logs/frontend_pricedata/recommendations/2018-09-11T15:10:47.296212+00:00.log`
But the correct filepath is `/home/ubuntu/airflow/logs/frontend_pricedata/recommendations/2018-09-11T15:10:47/1.log`

Is there a way to modify the log_filepath? In the config I could only find:
`log_filename_template = {{ ti.dag_id }}/{{ ti.task_id }}/{{ execution_date.strftime("%%Y-%%m-%%dT%%H:%%M") }}/{{ try_number }}.log` which appears to be correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there a way to modify the log_filepath the config key is `base_log_folder`.
But your filepath is correct , check the config file and set `task_log_reader` to `task`. In Airflow 1.9 the value is `file.task`.

For example:

```
# Log format
log_format = [%%(asctime)s] {%%(filename)s:%%(lineno)d} %%(levelname)s - %%(message)s
simple_log_format = %%(asctime)s %%(levelname)s - %%(message)s
log_filename_template = {{ ti.dag_id }}/{{ ti.task_id }}/{{ ts }}/{{ try_number }}.log
log_processor_filename_template = {{ filename }}.log
task_log_reader = task
```

There is a [Pull Request](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/pull/3881/files) to validate the config.

More details [Airflow Writing Logs](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/8100f1f27b651a66385b077863f72daf5c07a2cd/docs/howto/write-logs.rst)

Comment: Changing `task_log_reader` value to `task` instead of `file.task` did the trick. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I was following this answer as I am facing some issue as I am unable to capture airflow log but if I add `{{ ti.dag_id }}/{{ ti.task_id }}/{{ ts }}/{{ try_number }}.log` it says `ti` not defined. Even I am confused about the term `ti` should refer to an instance of task but not sure how.

Comment: @mad_   [Log filename format](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/76a5fc4d2eb3c214ca25406f03b4a0c5d7250f71/airflow/config_templates/default_airflow.cfg#L68)

Comment: @fengce but yet again ti seems to be referencing to a variable/class which is unclear.

Comment: @mad_ `ti` is default variables. same as  `task_instance` , the docs is [here](https://airflow.apache.org/code.html)